# When I clone my github project, my project don't working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Firstly, I'm sorry because my english is bad.

When I compile new project, It starts normally. Then I push my github repository this project and remove project from local. Then I clone project, I have too many exception.

For example:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties
>   
>   Task :app:validateSigningDebug FAILED
>   
>   Task :app:installDebug FAILED

I would like to learn that from you: I'm not sure, Maybe I don't push my project to github correctly way. (about that gitignore)

Is it allways so hard to  clone and start react-native project? where am i doing wrong [my project](https://github.com/DnzDmR/LocationTrackingApp)

Comment: Did you do a yarn install before trying to run the project?

Comment: Configuration that is specific to the local environment on the machine (like for example the SDK location) is usually not checked in to version control. After a fresh clone you may have to set this again.

Comment: @HMR yes, I before start the project, I run npm install command.

Comment: @Henry If this problem is normal, I have no problem.Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

Go to your React-native Project -> Android

Create a file **local.properties**

Open the file

paste your Android SDK path like below

in Windows

> sdk.dir = C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

in macOS

> sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk

in linux

> sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk

**Other hack**

If you have android studio simply open android folder of you react native project into android studio it will automatically set you path in local.properties file

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment @Vishal.  I've solved my problem.
We should use your resolution for local.properties error

The following solution should be applied for "app: validateSigningDebug FAILED" error

> cd ./android/app/ 
>  
>   keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

In addition, we must remove the existing application from the device.